# Não da submit com apenas 1 click em formulário se o foco estiver em um campo p:ajax

Tags: ajax, primefaces

Não estou conseguindo dar o submit no form com apenas um click. Quando clico em "Ok" o campo perde o Foco e processa o ajax. Ai tenho que clicar de novo para enviar.

```
...

<p:outputLabel value="Teste:" />                        
<p:inputText value="#{testeController.campoTeste}" id="campoTeste">
    <p:ajax listener="#{testePontoController.testeAjax}" event="blur" update="@this"/>
</p:inputText>

...

<p:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{testeController.cadastrarTest()}"/>

....
```

Alguém sabe como posso arrumar isto?

Obrigado

Comment: Meu caro, tente utilizar no seu botão o parâmetro 'process'(exemplo: process="@this", ou coloque o id do seu formulário) e veja se resolve. Se funcionar me avise, que posto como resposta.

Comment: Fiz o teste mas ainda não deu certo. Pelo que entendo, se o foco está no campo **Teste**, quando clico no botão **Ok** o campo perde o foco e automaticamente vai para o método que o ajax chama. Acho que preciso mudar a forma como está agora né... não usar o **event="blur**.

Comment: Adicione o process="@this" no ajax do evento blur senão ele não vai processar o novo valor.

Comment: Mesma coisa ainda... :(

Comment: Resolvido... não estou mais usando o `event="blur"`. Agora está sendo verificado na Controller. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui resolver da forma como queria, retirei a tag `p:ajax` e agora estou verificando na *Controller* no momento do *commit*.